# Outlook Online [new design]: displayReplyForm() opened without conversation history

Tags: office-js

After Microsoft added a new design to Outlook Online (toggle button 'The new Outlook' in the right upper corner), we faced a problem with office Add-in: message history is not displayed on 'reply'/'reply all' and 'forward'.

We use outlook API for replay, reply all and forward message windows. Before moving to the new design functions worked without any issues: Windows were opened with a message history. After turning on new outlook design these functions still open the window but without message history.

This is an example of my code to open reply window:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm(
   {
       'htmlBody': "Example text for body"
   });
```

Version of API we use:

- Outlook specific API library
- Version: 15.0.4615.1000

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We are looking into it.

Comment: Dear Outlook Add-ins Team, will the issue be fixed?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT please let us know when the issue will be resolved, that is very important!

Comment: Dear @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT do you have any updates around that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am feeling the same issue, so you can try using the function below:

```
  Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm(
  {
    toRecipients: Office.context.mailbox.item.to, // Copy the To line from current item
    ccRecipients: ['sam@contoso.com'],
    subject: 'Outlook add-ins are cool!',
    htmlBody: 'Hello <b>Push all content</b>!<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></i>',

  });
```

Inside the **htmlBody** param you can add full body with previews content. However, remember the restriction:

> The body content is limited to a maximum size of 32 KB.

I really hope the issue will be fixed ASAP!

Comment: Microsoft has fixed